# Prevent $element.on('click') before ajax is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making and ajax call and storing the results in an array. After the first set of data is loaded, I am using next and previous buttons to navigate through the array.

I want to prevent any $(element).on('click') events from happening until I have the first set of data loaded.

Is there any way to do this?

I have already tried to use

```
$(element).unbind('click');
```

for when the document loads and then

```
$(element).bind('click');
```

when the ajax call is successful, but still clicking on either the next or previous links will still trigger my

```
$('#next #prev').on('click', function () {
     //my code to navigate through the array here. 
});
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I can complete stop this event from firing until the ajax has loaded?

Comment: As far as I can see you did a mistake in the selector. Probably, it should be ``$('#next, #prev').on('click', ...);``

Comment: They are actually separate functions in my actual code, but yes, I made a typo here. The on click event i have in this example works fine in my code, I just need to know how to prevent it from being called until the ajax has loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable them by default and in the ajax success callback you can turn them on with something like this:

```
$(element).prop("disabled", false); // Element will get enabled for clicking
```

I will **update** the answer now as it is not working for the concerned person, to disable the button do this:

```
$(element).attr(“disabled”, true);
```

In success callback of the ajax call you need to do this:

```
$(element).removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: This doesnt work for me. The click event still fires.

Comment: did you disable the buttons @Narutkowski?

Comment: Yes I did a `$('#next').prop("disabled", true);` Then after my ajax fires I did a `$('#next').prop("disabled", true);`

Comment: Are you suggesting I add this attribute and then check for it before I am able to call my `$('#element').on('click', function () {});`?

Comment: It adds the attribute but even when I check against the attribute, it still fires the event. Now I am getting an warning `'Attr.nodeValue' is deprecated. Please use 'value' instead.` which is probably why it's not working.

Comment: It actually does work, but it's throwing the warning described in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    ....
    success:function(){
        $('#next #prev').on('click', function(){
            // only ajax event complete the #prev can run this function 
        }).off('click'); // no more clickable now
    }
});
```

or you can just

```
$('#next #prev').hide();
// done?
$('#next #prev').show();
```

Comment: I will most likely be showing and hiding the links, but this still did not solve my issue.